# Whitelisting '/' endpoint not working on Spring Security 6

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I'm following course on Spring Security, and Im trying to get it working on newest Spring Security 6. I'm trying to whitelist `localhost:8080/` from authentication using basic auth. But when I access the URL, it still asks me for credentials.

Currently I have this bean:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ApplicationSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        return http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                            auth.requestMatchers("/").permitAll();
                            auth.requestMatchers("index").permitAll();
                            auth.requestMatchers("/css/*").permitAll();
                            auth.requestMatchers("js/*").permitAll();
                            auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
                        }
                )
                .httpBasic(withDefaults()).build();
    }
}
```

But the default `/` endpoint, still is not whitelisted.

Comment: not sure but did you try this http.securityContext().requireExplicitSave(false)?

Comment: Could you please provide the regarding Controller class?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `@EnableWebSecurity` without `@Configuration` in your class, now when using Spring Security 6, **you should add the `@Configuration`** one since `@EnableWebSecurity` no longer includes `@Configuration` in it.

Spring Security 6

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Documented
@Import({ WebSecurityConfiguration.class, SpringWebMvcImportSelector.class, OAuth2ImportSelector.class,
        HttpSecurityConfiguration.class })
@EnableGlobalAuthentication
public @interface EnableWebSecurity {
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your input. I already use '@Configuration' annotation and the issue still persist. I tried to add the second one '@EnableWebSecurity', it doesnt work with this also. Any other ideas?

Comment: Your class is really basic. I don't think you should have any problem here. Be careful with requestMatchers("/"), if you're having @GetMapping(value = "") => it's equivalent to "localhost:8080" not include "localhost:8080/" as before (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#spring-mvc-and-webflux-url-matching-changes from Spring 6). So maybe you need to update your @GetMapping(value = "") to @GetMapping(value = "/")

Answer (score 1):

Reference: [spring-security/issues/12463](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/12463#issuecomment-1370260672)

Quoting [@jzheaux](https://github.com/jzheaux):

> The reason is that in 6.0, the authorization filter is run for all
> dispatcher types, including FORWARD. This means that the JSP that is
> forwarded to also needs to be permitted.
>
> You can achieve this by permitting FORWARDs:
>
> ````java
> http.authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
>     .dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.FORWARD).permitAll()
>     // ... the rest of your authorization rules ) ```
> ````
>
> [...]

For me, adding

```java
.authorizeHttpRequests((auth) -> {
    auth
        .shouldFilterAllDispatcherTypes(false)
        .requestMatchers("/", "/login", "/privacy-policy", "/legal", "/faq").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
})
```

did the trick.